# ASP.NET MVC 2 routing problems with string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, url-rewriting, url-routing

I want to add a simple route to my webapp, but it just doesn't work and i don't know why

code in global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "BrowseGenre",
            "{controller}/{action}/{genre}",
            new {controller = "Store", action = "Browse", genre = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

code in StoreController.cs:

```
    // GET: /Store/Browse
    public ActionResult Browse(string genreName)
    {

        var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Albums").Single(g => g.Name == genreName);
        //....
```

genreName is always null

the actionlinks are generated correctly (like domain.com/Store/Browse/Jazz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action parameter should be called `genre` instead of `genreName` (the same way it uis called in your route):

```
public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your anonymous type from

```
 new {controller = "Store", action = "Browse", genre = UrlParameter.Optional}
```

to

```
 new {controller = "Store", action = "Browse", genreName = UrlParameter.Optional}
```

OR

change the argument name in action from "genreName" to "genre" so that name of the member in the anonymous type matches the name of the argument in your action method.